Arbol AVL metodo delet
tengo un arbol AVL en el que quiero eliminar un elemento dada su key. Java me pierde un poco con el paso a valor y el paso por referencia, pensaba que era paso por referencia pero estoy un poco perdido. Y llevo unas cuantas horas probando como se podría eliminar, creo que poniendo lo a null pero tras debuggearlo veo que no elimina nada. ¿Que esta pasando?
    public void delete(K key) {
        if(delete(delete(root,key))!=null){
            size--;
        }
    }

    private Node<K> delete(Node<K> node, K key){
        if(node==null){
            return null;
        }else{
            int cmp = comparator.compare(key, node.key);
            if(cmp<0){
                return delete(node.left,key);
            }else if(cmp>0){
                return delete(node.right,key);
            }else{
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
    private Node<K> delete(Node<K> node){
        if(node==null){
            return null;
        }
        Node<K> aux = AVL.copyOf(node);

        node = null;

        if(aux.left!=null){
            aux.left=copyOf(aux.left);
            this.insert(aux.left.key);
            size--;
        }
        if(aux.right!=null){
            aux.right=copyOf(aux.right);
            this.insert(aux.right.key);
            size--;
        }
        return aux;
    }


En Java, cuando pasas referencias, estás pasando una copia de la referencia, por lo que al hacer node = null, solo cambias esa copia local, no el árbol real. Para eliminar un nodo en un árbol AVL, debes ajustar explícitamente los enlaces del nodo padre y luego rebalancear el árbol.
public void delete(K key) {
    root = delete(root, key);
}

private Node<K> delete(Node<K> node, K key) {
    if (node == null) return null;

    int cmp = comparator.compare(key, node.key);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        node.left = delete(node.left, key);
    } else if (cmp > 0) {
        node.right = delete(node.right, key);
    } else {
        if (node.left == null) return node.right;
        if (node.right == null) return node.left;
        
        Node<K> min = findMin(node.right);
        node.key = min.key;
        node.right = delete(node.right, min.key);
    }

    updateHeight(node);
    return balance(node);
}

private Node<K> findMin(Node<K> node) {
    while (node.left != null) node = node.left;
    return node;
}

Si pruebas así el código elimina correctamente el nodo, ajusta los enlaces y mantiene el balance del AVL. ;-)

Muchísimas gracias, he probado los métodos que me has proporcionado y funcionan de maravilla. Eso si, en mi caso la función updateHeight esta implícita en balance().
